# Counting Hits on a Page With a Random Extension

Tags: c++, web, google-analytics, counter

I currently have an application which always makes a request to a page with a '.data' extension every time it opens. This application is currently released to the public and people use it, and I want to see how many people use it. To do this, I am taking the approach of just counting how many times this page is downloaded. I want to use Google Analytics, but I cannot get javascript/html to run on this page because it has a 'data' extension (random).

Is there anyway I could get some javascript to run, or somehow count the amount of times this page is downloaded without having to change my current application and update it to make a request to a PHP page? Also, I've tried redirecting the page with the `.htaccess` to a PHP script, and my application that is currently public won't follow the redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you can't change put the following in your Apache configs?

AddType text/html .data